# how can i get length/runtime of a .swf object (a flash banner) with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a flash slide show created by jquery.  How do I detect the amount of time it takes for the flash banner to slide from the current banner to the next?

Comment: please show some code or give link which jquery plugin u r using

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any communication from flash to your web page in terms of events being dispatched when an swf reaches its final frame. You need to build this into your swf using:

```
ExternalInterface.call("javascriptMethodThatDoesNextSlideOnPage", args);
```

This would be placed on the last frame of your flash banner.